# How to display a tree-like hierarchy in a wordpress page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to display a a tree-like hierarchy of a company in a wordpress and when hovering on a certain member in this hierarchy you can display some of his information (some of these information are calculated from his row in the database)
this is an illustration of what i'm trying to make

[Responsabilty management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKJB9.png)

the numbers on the side are the number of tasks each member is responsible for the aim is to help each member identify what are his current tasks and who he should contact to ask about the progress.
I have tried making it with plain php and html but i could not integrate it with wordpress.
So my question is : how can I make a page like this in my wordpress website( should I use a plugin  or something?)

Comment: Just use custom post types (U can use Custom Post Types UI plugin to create it from WP backend). Each member can have an optional parent and from this you can render your tree structure.